# Prove that if $G$ has an exponent $n$ then the order of $G$ divides some power of $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

> Prove that if $G$ has an exponent $n$ then the order of $G$ divides some power of $n$.

I found the proof in Lang's Algebra on Page 33, revised Third edition,  section 6 of the first chapter. I'll mention briefly the parts I understood and the parts that I need help with.

It's a proof by induction, apparently. We first take a cyclic group generated by some element $b$ of $G$ and then show that the order of the cyclic group generated divides $n$. However, Lang then says that the order of $G/H$ divides a power of $n$ by induction.

My question is, what induction?

I think I get the rest of the proof, any help with this part will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Induction on the order of the finite group $G$. The group $G/H$ also has exponent $n$, so you can apply induction to it.

Comment: For  reference: Lang wrote a lot of books. Don't just say "in Lang". Specify the book, the edition, and the location. For example I'm going to guess that the group is supposed to be *abelian* (since you never mention that $H$ is normal). But I cannot verify, because I have no idea which page of which edition of which Lang book you are talking about.

Comment: I still kinda don't get it, can you dumb it down for me?

Comment: Lang's *Algebra* has gone through at least four editions (I own three of them; though one of the editions is called the "revised third edition" rather than the fourth), three different editorial houses. This seems to be Springer's Revised Third edition. And the groupo is supposed to be **abelian**.

Comment: Lang has never been a particularly good book to try to learn *from* (it is encyclopedic, great reference, but not very didactic). On the basis of the large number of questions you have run into in so few pages, it is clear that this book is not serving you well. I would encourage you to find a different book which is less complete but more self-learning friendly.

Answer (score 4):

This is part of the proof of Lemma 6.1, in Section I.6 of Lang's *Algebra*, revised 3rd Edition, Springer-Verlag.

Though you "forgot" to mention it, there is an assumption that $G$ is **finite abelian**. This is *incredibly* important for the proof you outline, since there is an immediate assumption that you can mod out by the subgroup $H$, even though it was never shown to be normal. Please try to include information that is **so** relevant that the proof makes no sense without it.

The induction is on the order of the group. Fix $n$. Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of exponent $n$, and we wish to show that the order of $G$ divides some power of $n$. Assume by induction that:

> If $A$ is any abelian group of order strictly smaller than $|G|$, and $A$ has exponent $n$, then the order of $A$ divides some power of $n$.

That is, we are doing strong induction on the order of $G$.

Let $b\in G$, $b\neq 1$, and let $H=\langle b\rangle$. The order of $H$ divides $n$, because $b^n=1$ (since $G$ has exponent $n$). Now let $A=G/H$. This is a group of order strictly smaller than $|G|$ (it has order $|G|/|H|$ and $|H|\gt 1$), and has exponent $n$ (any quotient of a group of exponent $n$ has exponent $n$). So by the induction hypothesis, $|A|$ divides a power of $n$; say $|A|$ divides $n^r$. Then $|G|/|H|$ divides $n^r$, so $|G|$ divides $|H|n^r$. But since $|H|$ divides $n$, then $|H|n^r$ divides $nn^r=n^{r+1}$. Thus, $|G|$ divides $n^{r+1}$, proving the result for $G$.

The strong induction argument assumes that $G$ has nontrivial elements, so we need to prove a special case: if $G$ has no nontrivial elements, then $|G|=1$, which of course divides $n$, a power of $n$.

Comment: Isn't there an easy proof that doesn't require an abelian group? The exponent of $G$ and its order must have the same prime divisors (this is Cauchy+Lagrange+basic number theory), so one is a divisor of a power of the other (basic number theory). Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @verret: This is fairly early in Lang; I don’t recall off-hand what he has available. And he isn’t even stating this as a result: it’s the first step in a proof of something else, which *is* for finite abelian groups.,

Comment: I see, that makes sense.

Comment: late comment here. I don't think the exponent of quotient group equals the exponent of group. For example in $\mathbb{Z_{10}}$ the exponent is $10$ . But the exponent of $\mathbb{Z_{10}}/<2>$ is just $2$. So I think it is just better to use that the exponent of the quotient group divides the exponent of the group. That also leads to the same conclusion.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron You are misinterpreting the statement. "$G$ has exponent $n$" means $x^n=e$ for every $x\in G$. There is no assertion. that $n$ is the **smallest** integer that works.  Notice that the statement says "**an** exponent" (indefinite article), not **the** exponent; if your interpretation of the term were correct (which it isn't) then you would use the definite singular article.

Comment: Ah I get it. My bad. I thought exponent means the smallest integer for which $g^{n}=e\,\forall g\in G$